# Erro ao importar SKLEARN 32b em servidor 64b

Tags: python, sklearn

tudo bem?
Estou realmente desesperado com uma dúvida:
Tenho um ambiente Python 3.7 montado em uma máquina, Windows 10 64b, e preciso migrar ele (que já vem funcionando à algum tempo) para outra Server 64b.
Por motivos de compatibilidade com a minha base de dados Oracle utilizo o Python 3.7 32b (não posso trocá-lo). Entretanto ao rodar um dos meus algoritmos, mais exatamente ao importar a lib sklearn recebo o seguinte erro como resposta:
**from ._sparsetools import csr_tocsc, csr_tobsr, csr_count_blocks, \
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.**
Já rodei vários fóruns e não sei como solucionar este problema, alguém poderia me ajudar?
Vale frisar que não posso migrar para um arquitetura 32 e nem usar o Python 64.

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido, instalei uma versão anterior do Python, neste caso a 3.5 (32b) e o sistema voltou a funcionar perfeitamente!